# Error pgAdmin SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, pgadmin

estoy empezando con SQL y al hacer esta consulta me devuelve este error:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
JOIN tableB b ON a.atr1 = b.atr2
JOIN tableC C ON b.atr3 = c.art1
WHERE a = 3
ORDER BY a ASC;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo he intentado todo y no funciona. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Que es a? , si puedieras agregar la estructura de tus tablas estaria mejor

Comment: Te falta poner el alias a la 1ª tabla: `SELECT * FROM tableA a`, te recomiendo que uses siempre `AS` para mantener el estándar y que uses siempre un estilo *case sensitive* y que apliques la *uniformidad* en tu código, por ejemplo, declaras el alias `C` en mayúscula y luego lo usas en minúscula. Si todos los alias están en minúscula, ¿por qué pones `C` en mayúscula?

Answer (score 1):

No le asignaste el alias a la primer tabla y parece que falta la columna del WHERE puesto que parece solo el alias de la tabla faltante.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b ON a.atr1 = b.atr2
JOIN tableC C ON b.atr3 = c.art1
WHERE a.columna = 3
ORDER BY a.columna ASC;
```